# Reading specific HTML Content specified by TAG and ID

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `Invoke-WebRequest` command.

For testing purposes, I'm using an old website project of mine.
The website contains several dynamic (self Updating) DIVs with ID-Names which defines the DIV function. (like: `<div id="eventlogs">` or `<div id="chatwindow">`)

I'm now searching for a way to read the whole content of these specific div containers including the HTML code inside the div.

I'd like something similar to this, so that I can put it into a function to get the code of each div container into an separate `$variable`

```
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:6642/"
($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("div") | Where {$_.className -eq "chatwindow"}).innerText
```

can someone give me a head start into the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an hashtable to save the info :

```
$r=iwr http://yahoo.fr
$cpt=1                                                                                                                                                                                                             
$resu=@{}

$r.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagname("div") |%{
    if ($_.id -eq $null){ $_.id="div$cpt";$cpt++}
    $resu[$($_.id)]=$_.innerHTML
}                                                                                       
$resu
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I only edited $cpt to: `$cpt=0`. That seems a bit more logical to me :-)

However, I can get the results only by inserting the code manually into the shell.
If I write it into a .ps script and try the output `$resu.chatwindow` or inserting it into a richtextbox `$richtextboxCode.Text = $resu.chatwindow | Out-String` I dont get any results displayed. Am I missing something?

Comment: this is normal : the result variable  only exists at the time you execute the script (script scope). If I catched you, you can use the $resu var outside the script if you declare this variable as a global one : `$global:resu=@{}`  .

Comment: my bad. my textbox had another variable.
it's working now. Can you tell me what I have to do if I want the complete Code+Text of the div? I do also need the text inside the div

Comment: Try to select outterText property.

Comment: hmm... doesn't seem to work if there other divs nested into the main div.
But I think I can find a solution from here on. Thanks.